# jquery sortable connect with, move items only from left to right

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a jquery UI sortable connectwith page as

```
    <div class="left_column"> 
             <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
                <li>Item 1</li> 
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 4</li>
                <li>Item 5</li>
            </ul>          
    </div>

    <div class="right_column">
            <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 4</li>
                <li>Item 5</li>
            </ul>                  
    </div>
```

and jquery

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
});
</script>
```

now it works very well, but I only want to move items from left_column to right_column, users will not be able to move items from right_column to left_column, also the can move up/down in both columns

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you dont have to connect both. just connect sortable 1 with sortable 2

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
        connectWith: "#sortable2"
    }).disableSelection();

     $( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
     }).disableSelection();

});
</script>
```